# Is it safe to ignore the 'Packages' folder in Unity 2018?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just updated my `Unity` from `2017.3.1f1` to `2018.2.1f1` and when I opened my project it moved the `manifest.json` file from the `UnityPackageManager` folder to the `Packages` folder. Also, it created a bunch of files and folders in the `Packages` folder.

My question is:

Is it safe to ignore the `Packages` folder from the repository, especially `manifest.json`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**manifest.json** contains list of your dependencies(the packages you have used for your project). so if You clone your repository on a different machine, unity uses this list to download the required packages.

**short answer**: You should not put Packages in your .gitignore. It should be committed along with the rest of your project files.

Comment: just to clarify. then is it fine to **add packages folder into gitignore** with an **exception** for **manifest.json**  ?
**edit** i am confused with new packages folder that show up in unity editor containing multiple file that i didnt knoew

Answer (score 6):

Not a lot of google results for this, so for future searchers I will add:

It seems in Unity 2020.1 (and probably earlier) that the actual package contents are held in `Library/PackageCache`, and only the manifest file lives in the root `Packages` folder.

If `Library` is ignored as it should be, then there is no additional entry needed in the `.gitignore`.